# "sum" time execution in sparql

Tags: rdf, sparql

I have to check the consistency of a dataset regarding stated population; the sum of the population of all administrative units A of level L must be equal to the population of the administrative units B of level L+1 to which all administrative units A belong. This can be only in a single query. I've tried with the following code, but the result was nothing (condition doesn't seem to work).  I guess that there is no result because of the "sum" time execution.  What can I do to fix this?

```
prefix ns:   <http://geo.linkedopendata.gr/gag/ontology/>

SELECT ?condition WHERE {
  ?x  ns:has_official_name  ?decentralized . 
  ?x  ns:has_population  ?decentralized_population . 
  ?y  ns:has_official_name  ?region . 
  ?y  ns:has_population  ?region_population . 
  ?z  ns:has_official_name  ?regional_unit . 
  ?z  ns:has_population  ?regional_unit_population .
  ?z  ns:belongs_to  ?y . 
  ?y  ns:belongs_to  ?x . 
  FILTER regex(str(?decentralized), \"DECENTRALIZED\") .
  FILTER regex(str(?region), \"REGION\") .
  FILTER regex(str(?regional_unit), \"REGIONAL UNIT\") .
  FILTER (!regex(str(?region), \"REGIONAL\")) . 
  BIND(SUM(?decentralized_population) AS ?sum_decentralized_population) .
  BIND(SUM(?region_population) AS ?sum_region_population) .
  BIND(SUM(?regional_unit_population) AS ?sum_regional_unit_population) .
  OPTIONAL {
    BIND( IF(?sum_decentralized_population = ?sum_region_population &&
             ?sum_region_population = ?sum_regional_unit_population, 'TRUE', 'FALSE')
           AS ?condition) .
  }
}
GROUP BY ?condition
```

@Joshua, suppose we have 7 units at level L. These are:

A: with population:100

B: with population:150

C: with population:300

D: with population:200

E: with population:250

F: with population:150

G: with population:150

At level L+1 we have 13 units, where:

unit_1: has population 30 and belongs to A

unit_2: has population 70 and belongs to A

unit_3: has population 80 and belongs to B

unit_4: has population 70 and belongs to B

unit_5: has population 200 and belongs to C

unit_6: has population 100 and belongs to C

unit_7: has population 130 and belongs to D

unit_8: has population 70 and belongs to D

unit_9: has population 180 and belongs to E

unit_10: has population 70 and belongs to E

unit_11: has population 150 and belongs to F

unit_12: has population 100 and belongs to G

unit_13: has population 50 and belongs to G

At level L+2 we have 74 units, where:

unit_a: has population 15 and belongs to unit_1

unit_b: has population 5 and belongs to unit_1

unit_c: has population 3 and belongs to unit_1

unit_d: has population 7 and belongs to unit_1

unit_e: has population 40 and belongs to unit_1

unit_f: has population 20 and belongs to unit_1

unit_g: has population 10 and belongs to unit_1

and so on...(The amount of population is not the real one)

Now, I have to check if the population of unit A (100 at level L) is equal to:

1. the sum of population of unit_1 and unit_2 (30 +70 at level L+1)
2. the sum of population of unit_a, unit_b, unit_c, unit_d, unit_e, unit_f and unit_g (15 + 5 + 3 + 7 + 40 + 20 + 10 at level L+2)

.....................

6. the sum of population of all units at level L+5)

I work with sesame in eclipse and my query is:

String queryStringAndy = "PREFIX rdf: http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" +
                         "PREFIX gag: http://geo.linkedopendata.gr/gag/ontology/" +

" SELECT DISTINCT ?dec_pop  (SUM(?reg_pop) AS ?sum_reg_pop) (SUM(?reg_unit_pop) AS ?sum_reg_unit_pop) (SUM(?mun_pop) AS ?sum_mun_pop)" +

" WHERE { ?x rdf:type gag:Decentralized_Unit ." +

" ?x  gag:has_official_name  ?decentralized . " +

" ?x  gag:has_population ?dec_pop . " +

" ?y  rdf:type gag:Region ." +

" ?y  gag:has_official_name  ?region . " +

" ?y  gag:has_population  ?reg_pop . " +

" ?z  rdf:type gag:Regional_Unit ." +

" ?z  gag:has_official_name ?regional_unit . " +

" ?z  gag:has_population  ?reg_unit_pop . " +

" ?w  rdf:type gag:Municipality ." +

" ?w  gag:has_official_name ?municipality . " +

" ?w  gag:has_population  ?mun_pop . " +

" ?y  gag:belongs_to  ?x ." +

" ?z  gag:belongs_to  ?y ." +

" ?w  gag:belongs_to  ?z .}" +

" GROUP BY ?dec_pop " ;

dec_pop: the population of units at level L

reg_pop: the population of units at level L+1

reg_unit_pop: the population of units at level L+2

mun_pop: the population of units at level L+3

The strange thing is that when I have to compare the ?dec_pop with only one sum expression, the result is correct. But when I put more sums, only the sum of the units at the last computing level is equal to ?dec_pop. I hope this is more clear now.

Comment: You don't escape quotes in a SPARQL query.  E.g., `FILTER regex(str(?region), \"REGION\")` isn't legal.  Can you should us the actual query you're using, along with some sample data.  It's very hard to say what your query should return when we can't see the query and data.

Comment: Please read the formatting guidelines.  You are posting code as plain text, and posting code instead of queries.  If you can show us actual data that we could copy and paste to recreate the problem, it will be much easier for people to help.  Otherwise,  it's just not clear what you're asking, and it's not a problem that any of us can reproduce.

Answer (score 3):

Your query as written isn't legal SPARQL (e.g., you shouldn't escape quotes) and you haven't shown us data, so it's hard to say what's actually going wrong in your query.  However, what you're trying to do is achievable in SPARQL.  E.g., suppose you've got this data where things can have children, and things can have counts:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:a :count 23 ;
   :hasChild :b, :c .

:b :count 10 .

:c :count 13 ;
   :hasChild :d, :e .

:d :count 6 .
:e :count 6 .
```

Now, the first thing is to retrieve the data that you want.  You can retrieve each node with children, its declared count, and the sum of the count of its children with a query like this:

```
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?x ?count (sum(?_subcount) as ?subcount) where {
  ?x :count ?count ;
     :hasChild/:count ?_subcount
}
group by ?x ?count
```

```
-------------------------
| x  | count | subcount |
=========================
| :a | 23    | 23       |
| :c | 13    | 12       |
-------------------------
```

The declared value for :a is right, but :c's is wrong.  You can select just the inconsistent values by filtering with **having**:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?x ?count (sum(?_subcount) as ?subcount) where {
  ?x :count ?count ;
     :hasChild/:count ?_subcount
}
group by ?x ?count
having (?count != ?subcount)
```

```
-------------------------
| x  | count | subcount |
=========================
| :c | 13    | 12       |
-------------------------
```

It shouldn't be too hard to update this example to your actual data.

Comment: The query as written is far more illegal than just bad escaping, aggregate expressions are only usable as `SELECT` expressions or in `HAVING` clauses and a conforming SPARQL processor should have rejected that query as illegal

Comment: @RobV I agree. I'm guessing that the code was a "sanitized" version of some string concatenation code (there was a semicolon at the end, and there were escaped quotes).  It's not clear from the question what the *actual* error was, but fortunately the intent was clear enough.

Comment: Joshua thank you very much for your reply. You gave me great help. You're right about the wrong syntax. But I'm very new in SPARQL and I'm trying to figure out how this works...

Comment: @Andy Did this end up working for you?  If it did, you should consider (but are certainly not required to) [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/225437).  If not, are you still having issues getting the sums that you need?

Comment: Joshua I didn't have the time to check it but I'll do it today. As soon as I check it I'll let you know.

Comment: Dear Joshua it didn't work! But let me explain you what I ask for: We have a country which has 6 levels of administrative units. Each level has a number of administrative units each one of them has a specific population. So at the top level we have 6 decentralized administrations, and each one of them has a stated population. At the next bellow level we have 13 regions, and also each one of them has a stated population.

Comment: What I want is to check if the sum of population of all decentralized administrations is equal to the sum of population of all regions and if the sum of population of all regions is equal to the sum of population of all regional units(which are at 3rd level) adn so on until level 6. So the ?count has to be a "sum" like the "(sum(?_subcount) as ?subcount)". I tried to put a 2nd sum instead of ?count but it didn't work... Please help!

Comment: @Andy "I tried to put a 2nd sum instead of ?count but it didn't work... "  If you don't show exactly what you tried, then we can't really help you debug it.  Feel free to edit/update your question.  I sounds like maybe you want something like this.  A has subunits B and C.  B has subunits D and E.  C has subunits F and G.  You want to check that A = D+E+F+G, and that B=D+E, and that C=F+G?  I.e., check each unit and the bottom level units below it?

Comment: @Andy Again, this would be *MUCH* easier if you provided some sample data in the question and provided a by-hand example of the result that you're trying to achieve.  At the moment, we're just guessing about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Joshua, suppose we have 7 units at level L. These are:
A: with population:100
B: with population:150
C: with population:300
D: with population:200
E: with population:250
F: with population:150
G: with population:150

At level L+1 we have 13 units, where:
unit_1: has population 30 and belongs to A
unit_2: has population 70 and belongs to A
unit_3: has population 80 and belongs to B
unit_4: has population 70 and belongs to B
unit_5: has population 200 and belongs to C
unit_6: has population 100 and belongs to C

Comment: unit_7: has population 130 and belongs to D
unit_8: has population 70 and belongs to D
unit_9: has population 180 and belongs to E
unit_10: has population 70 and belongs to E
unit_11: has population 150 and belongs to F
unit_12: has population 100 and belongs to G
unit_13: has population 50 and belongs to G

At level L+2 we have 74 units, where:
unit_a: has population 15 and belongs to unit_1
unit_b: has population 5 and belongs to unit_1
unit_c: has population 3 and belongs to unit_1
unit_d: has population 7 and belongs to unit_1

and so on...

Comment: " ?z  gag:has_official_name ?regional_unit . " +
" ?z  gag:has_population  ?reg_unit_pop . " +
" ?w  rdf:type gag:Municipality ." +
" ?w  gag:has_official_name ?municipality . " +
" ?w  gag:has_population  ?mun_pop . " +
" ?y  gag:belongs_to  ?x ." +
" ?z  gag:belongs_to  ?y ." +
" ?w  gag:belongs_to  ?z .}" +
" GROUP BY ?dec_pop " ;

Comment: dec_pop: the population of units at level L
reg_pop: the population of units at level L+1
reg_unit_pop: the population of units at level L+2
mun_pop: the population of units at level L+3

Comment: The strange thing is that when I have to compare the ?dec_pop with only one sum expression, the result is correct. But when I put more sums, only the sum of the units at the last level is equal to ?dec_pop. I hope this is more clear now.

Comment: @Andy I'm not going to try to read code in comments.  There's an "edit" link under your question for a reason.  Comments can be deleted at any time, which means that any answer that depends on information in comments can easily be outdated.   Plus, comments lose formatting. Does your code *really* say `PREFIX rdf: <w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"` without any `http://` before `w3.org`?  I doubt it.  Be sure to proofread your comments, too.